# How to create tree format form array in angular14?

Tags: angular

I have attached my code link. I tried create dynamic nested tree format form array. But I don't know how to create. I am new in angular framework.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vytk36?file=src/index.html

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: That's a lot of code. It would be better to add the part that is causing you trouble to the question.

Comment: You want to create a FormArray of a FormAray, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73483552/angular-problem-with-formarray-in-formarray/73484029#73484029) or [this another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73483552/angular-problem-with-formarray-in-formarray/73484029#73484029)

Comment: @Eliseo I am trying to data structures tree format form array. It is possible to create using angular form array?

Comment: How many "deeps" have your structure, one, two, three, undefined? can you put an example of the .json you want to mannage?

Comment: @Eliseo   {
  "menu": [
    {
      "nestedmenu": [
        {
          "nestedmenu": [
            {}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}   level no end... It is possible to create?

Comment: @Arunkumar, sure! (impossible is nothing) but it's a bit complex. I just added an answer. I hope can help

Comment: @Eliseo I have tried this format {
  "menu": [
    {
      "nestedmenu": [
        {
          "nestedmenu": [
            {
              "nestedmenu": [],
              "submenu": []
            }
          ],
          "submenu": []
        }
      ],
      "submenu": []
    }
  ]
} How to add submenu. Please help me.

Comment: I have tried but I got some issue. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pezmpp?file=src/form.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always we have a "infinite level" is work to make a "recursive component"

A recursive component is only a component that call itself (see e.g. [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55305905/how-can-i-create-a-nested-recursive-table-that-can-drill-down-x-levels-in-angul/55315414#55315414))

Mannage a child component that mannage a formGroup from parent it's not very easy. We can use viewProviders or pass the FormGroup in an input (see [this another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75914148/reactive-form-angular-and-pass-controls/75916598#75916598))

We are going to choose pass the formGroup. But as our component is a recursive component we need in witch formGroup we are, so I use another input that it's the "name" of the formGroup. (remember that our formArrays are formArrays of formGroups. We need "reach" the formGroup

Puff...!

Before we are going to define a function to create the formGroup. We are export it because the same function can be used by the parent and by the component

```
export function setNestedMenu(data:any=null){
  data=data || {name: "",displayname: "",id: "",nestedMenu: []}
  return new FormGroup({
      name:new FormControl(data.name),
      displayName:new FormControl(data.name),
      id:new FormControl(data.name),
      nestedMenu:new FormArray(data.nestedMenu.map((x:any)=>this.setNestedMenu(x)))
  })
}
```

NOTE: I use camelCase to give value to the "properties"

The component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'form-component',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
  <div [style.margin-left.px]="index*10" *ngIf="formGroup" [formGroup]="formGroup" >
  <div formArrayName="nestedMenu">
     <button (click)="addMenu()">add</button>
     <div *ngFor="let group of menuArray?.controls;let i=index" 
                                          [formGroupName]="i">
       <input formControlName="id"/>
       <input formControlName="name"/>
       <input formControlName="displayName"/>
       <button (click)="removeMenu(i)">remove</button>
       <button (click)="addSubMenu(i)">add submenu</button>
       <ng-container *ngIf="getSubMenuArray(i).length">
         <!--here we call again to our component-->
          <form-component [form]="form" 
                          [name]="name+'.'+i+'.nestedMenu'" 
                          [index]="index+1" ></form-component>
       </ng-container>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>`,
})
export class FormMenuComponent  {
  _index:number=0;
  formGroup:FormGroup
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  @Input() name:string="nestedMenu";
  @Input('index') set _(value:number){
    this._index=value;
    this.formGroup=(value?this.form.get(this.name).parent:this.form) as FormGroup
  }

  get index()
  {
    return this._index
  }
  get menuArray() {
    return this.form?this.form.get(this.name) as FormArray:null;
  }
  getSubMenuArray(index:number){
    
    return this.form.get(this.name+'.'+index+'.nestedMenu') as FormArray
  }
  
 addMenu()
 {
   this.menuArray.push(setNestedMenu())
 }
 addSubMenu(index:number)
 {
   this.getSubMenuArray(index).push(setNestedMenu())
 }
 removeMenu(index:number)
 {
  this.menuArray.removeAt(index)
 }
}
```

See how pass the name, the form and the index variables

Our main.component simply

```
<form-component [form]="form" [index]="0"></form-component>

form: FormGroup=new FormGroup({
    nestedMenu:new FormArray([setNestedMenu()])
  })
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skjkp4?file=src%2Fform.component.ts)

NOTE: sorry for self quoting

Comment: I have tried modification some customize. But I got some issue. stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pezmpp?file=src/form.component.ts Please help me

Comment: i have add extra submenu array in this form. But i got issue Please help me. I have attached code URL. I don't know how to fix this error. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pezmpp?file=src/form.component.ts

Comment: @Arunkumar, sorry for the delay (I was very busy the last week). I added a new answer that I hope can help

Answer (score 0):

The before answer pass to the form two variables: the "form" and the "name" of the formArray. This complicate the component. There're another better aproach that it's pass the "formGroup".

The first is that our component has an "setter" input like

```
  formGroup:FormGroup
  @Input('form') set __(value:AbstractControl){
    this.formGroup=value as FormGroup
  }
```

(It's necessary to "cast" the control)

Now we can use some like

```
<div *ngIf="formGroup" [formGroup]="formgroup">
  ...
  <div formArrayName="nestedMenu">
     <div *ngFor="let group of nestedMenuArray?.controls;let i=index"
                [formGroupName]="i">
        ...
        <ng-container *ngIf="getNestedMenuArray(i)?.length">
          <!--see we pass as form the "formGroup"-->
          <form-component [form]="nestedMenuArray.at(i)"  [index]="index+1" >
          </form-component>
        </ng-container>
     </div>
  </div>

  get nestedMenuArray() {
     return this.formGroup?this.formGroup.get('nestedMenu') as FormArray:null;
  }

  getNestedMenuArray(index:number){
    return  this.nestedMenuArray?this.nestedMenuArray.at(index) as FormArray:null
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvgy6k?file=src%2Fform.component.ts,src%2Fform.component.html)